# :not() doesn't work as expected

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
div.entry-content:not(body.single div.entry-content)
{
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
    margin-top:10px;
    line-height: 114%;
    font-size:15px;
}
```

the above css doesn't effect any elements at all ....I want `div.entry-content` elements that exist inside a `body` with the class `single` to be styled differently from the rest `div.entry-content`elements ..

```
body.single div.entry-content
{}
```

and

```
div.entry-content
{}
```

do seem to work just fine .. but

```
div.entry-content:not(body.single div.entry-content)
{}
```

doesn't seem to

Comment: The `:not` pseudo-class only takes a simple selector..and certainly not a parent selector.

Comment: is there some way to work around that to achieve what I want ?

Comment: @user4777975: Take a look at my answer, it should solve your issue.

Comment: You could use the cascading feature of CSS to achieve this. Write the styles you want for the div.entry-content elements, and then, after that CSS, write the styles you want for the body.single div.entry-content elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to rewrite the selector line to work the way you intend it to:

```
body:not(.single) div.entry-content {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-top:10px;
  line-height: 114%;
  font-size:15px;
}
```

[This CSS Tricks page](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/) elaborates on the fact that you may only use a simple selector within a `:not` pseudo-class, which they define as follows in the footnote:

> A simple selector is classified as a Type Selector, Universal Selector, Attribute Selector, Class Selector, ID Selector, or Pseudo Class Selector.

Answer (score 1):

> I want `div.entry-content` elements that exist inside a `body` with the
>   class `single` to be styled differently from the rest
>   `div.entry-content` elements

If you really want to use the `:not()` selector then you need to do something like this:

```css
body:not(.single) div.entry-content {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 114%;
  font-size: 15px;
  /* demo*/
  background: red
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="entry-content">test
  </div>
</body>
```

---

with class `single` in `body`

```css
body:not(.single) div.entry-content {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 114%;
  font-size: 15px;
  /* demo*/
  background: red
}
```

```html
<body class="single">
  <div class="entry-content">test
  </div>
</body>
```

See more info in MDN about [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

> The negation CSS pseudo-class, `:not(X)`, is a functional notation
>   taking a simple selector X as an argument. It matches an element that
>   is not represented by the argument. X must not contain another
>   negation selector.

Comment: Nice exact copy of my answer. It's a good answer, though, I give you that! :)

Comment: Well it is the only way of using `:not` so the code has to be the same, but no I didn't copy anything from you, in regard to your content, **therefore not an exact copy** ;) Plus I did use stack snippets ;)

Comment: Fair enough, though I like to keep simple answers short myself.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body:not(.single) div.entry-content {
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 114%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color:white;
    background:green;
}
```

```html
  <div class="single">
         this is the single div
         <div class="entry-content">
           write some text inside entry content
         </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: If you take a close look at the question, it's the `body` element that has the class, not some random element. You just made up some markup on your own, encountering the same problem as the questioner, who wanted to style all elements that **aren't** children of the `.single` element...

Comment: The CSS part of the solution is accurate (though not different from what's already posted in the slightest), but your example HTML doesn't even include a body element... your style still shows up with a green backgground, even though that's what the questioner *tried to avoid*